# Google Cloud Storage URL expires after a day

Tags: django, google-cloud-storage

I switched to google cloud recently for my django app, all works well except that the url to some of my pictures coming from google cloud storage keeps getting expired after a day, and this is really terrible as there is always broken images on my app. I have even set my bucket to public, and still the urls expires after a day. I get this message when i try to access the image.

```
    <Error>
        <Code>ExpiredToken</Code>
        <Message>The provided token has expired.</Message>
        <Details>
        Request signature expired at: 2020-04-16T17:28:36+00:00
        </Details>
    </Error>
```

How can one change this?

Comment: Please edit the question to illustrate how you are getting these URLs, perhaps pointing to the documentation you are using.  There are different types of URLs that could link to content in Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you are providing Signed URL to your front-end and this URL's are expiring. 
As you can see in the [Public Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)

> The typical way to address this use case is to provide a signed URL to
>   a user, which gives the user read, write, or delete access to that
>   resource for a limited time. You specify an expiration time when you
>   create the signed URL

This means that using Signed URL may not be the best approach for your app. This only will be usefull if every time that your user logs into your application you generate a new Signed URL for this specific user (which may be overcomplicated for your use case or not)

If you are making your object public what you probably are trying to do is to use the URL link instead. This URL have the following form:

```
https://storage.cloud.google.com/YOUR_BUCKET/YOUR_IMAGE.PNG
```

Passing this URL instead of the Signed URL will stop "making your urls to expires after a day".

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I already figured out that just using the public url would eliminate this error. However, my app allows that other users be able to make a post directly from their end. I was thinking splitting the public signed url from the given signed url dynamically would do the trick, but I don't know if there would be a downside to this. Technically, I would use javascript to achieve this though.

Comment: For whatever you want to share publically and you don't mind that anybody can acces just use the public URL link. Use Signed URL only for information that you want to be accesible only for a specific user/group for a limited ammount of time. Im not aware of the flow that you applications follows to upload/give permissions. If you want suggestions on this please expand your question with a detailed outline on the workflow of your app and the desired result